# How to store login details like time of login and which machine (ip address)

Tags: php, authentication

I am beginner to php.

My project in php , backend sql.

I have a login form.I want to maintain activity log.How to do that?

That includes:

```
         1.Login time Logout time

         2. Machine Name(IP address) 

         3.status( sign in pass/fail)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use php functionality here.

Do like this:

```
 1.Login time Logout time
 $time = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

 2. Machine Name(IP address) 
 $ipaddr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

 3.status( sign in pass/fail)
 You need to check this using mysql query.
```

Let me know for more help.

Comment: Thanks.which way is better to store these data "session","cookies",or "mysql"?

Comment: I think `mysql` as `session` and `cookie` will remove at certain point.

Comment: ya.i read like this in some other post.I think is better to save in database.Confused.

Comment: @ Cric Favor  When i use your code i got ipaddress like this  "::1".Any solution. php version: 5.6.2

Comment: Did you mean in internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem.

Code for get ip address with machine name:

```
         <?php

         $machineName = gethostname();   //for get current system name 

         $ip = gethostbyname($machineName); //For get ipaddress

        ?>
```